# Use [read more] tag on a Page

Tags: wordpress

I want to insert a Read More / See More tag in my Wordpress page. But the problem is that when I try to do it and use the short code `<!--more-->` it doesn't work and I found out the this only works on post pages.

Could someone help me about this, I really need your expert help. Thanks.

Comment: Google not work for you? http://wordpress.org/plugins/better-read-more/

Comment: So this is a static content page, not a post? What's the behaviour you want - the rest of the text start hidden but appear in place? Normally I think the read more redirects you to the complete post page: where would you start to see the partial content?

Comment: I want the behavior to be like when you click the read more button it wont go to another link / page but either it stays on same page displaying the content inside the read more button

Comment: @Alex I tried to Google it but the link you give to me is so new :) thanks anyway, I would try this

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, I suggest the "better read more" plugin:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/better-read-more

Comment: But wait I'm using it now so here it goes. When I try putting another paragraph with another read more button on it my first paragraph with a read more button too suddenly did not function. I mean the Read more button on my first paragraph suddenly disappears when I try putting another Read more button with the other paragraph that I place below

Comment: Oh I see, do you know any Wordpress plugin that works and give me my desired output ? I'm still in a struggle with this problem